# Elastic Search automatic rollover index

Tags: elasticsearch

May I ask if there is builtin solution in ES to rollover the index automatically. For example, the following is what i have achieved so far:

1. Create an index called "idx-000001", and an alias to it as "idx-prod"
2. Setup rollover policy to "idx-prod" by doing for instance:

   curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/idx-prod/_rollover?pretty' -d'{
   "conditions": {
   "max_age":   "7d",
   "max_docs":  100000
   }
   }'
3. Inject data to "idx-prod", when hitting 100000 documents, ES rolls over to "idx-000002"

But without setting up a rollover policy again with "idx-prod", it will stop the rollover for "idx-000002".

May i ask if there is a builtin and automatic solution for the idx rollover ?
It appears to me idx template possibly can help out here, but i have no luck to try it successfully.

Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

not automated but you could schedule and take a look at curator. https://github.com/elastic/curator

Answer (score 3):

As of elasticsearch 6.6 you have ILM (Index Lifecycle Managment)
And You can add a rollover to a phase:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/using-policies-rollover.html

Comment: ILM is a good solution to automate indices rollover BUT only if you have XPack ! So curator seems the solution without XPack